# How can I draw this background without a real BG image (using canvas/css3?)

Tags: css, canvas, css-transitions

Im building an app using Ionic2 and I need to add this background (light blue with lines) to my app background:
[image: background image]
and I don't want to import an image for that (using html5 canvas &/or CSS3).

anyone can help me with it?

Here is my css:

```
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-color: #01c4cd;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What you want can be done with CSS gradients.

Comment: Ill try now, Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a canvas or a background image. You can achieve this with css gradients:

```css
#background { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  
  background-image:
        
    /* Line 1 */
    linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 63%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 64%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 65%),
      
    /* Line 2 */
    linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 78%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 79%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%),
    
    /* Blue background gradient */
    linear-gradient(45deg, #1f579b 0%,#7bdce5 100%);   
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
```

There's a few different ways to achieve this, but in this example there's one div with a full-size blue gradient in the background, and two overlaying, smaller white gradients creating the lines. You can add more lines, change their color etc. to get the effect you're looking for.

You could combine the `linear-gradient` statements to keep file size smaller, but they're separately here for improved readability.

Comment: Thanks, But sorry, I didn't mean the 3d shape :), Just the gradient lines over the background color.. It was just a screenshot.

Comment: @EranLevi Sorry, I misunderstood you. I edited me answer.

Comment: Exactly why I needed! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: CSS gradients are technically background-images but yep :) ah and you can add multiple background-image properties (therefor gradients) to the same element.

Comment: @Kaiido I always forget about applying multiple background to one element, that's a good catch. Thanks! As for the gradients being images, you are of course technically correct, but I think the implied meaning here was a bitmap image.